# sending calendar in mails using django

Tags: python, django

I am using mandrill for sending mails after registering the events-

```
mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY)
    message = {
        'html': template_func,
        'from_email': 'email@xyz',
        'from_name': 'any_name',
        'global_merge_vars': [],
        # need reply mail
        'headers': {'Reply-To': 'email@xyz'},
        'merge': True,
        'merge_language': 'mailchimp',
        'subject': "Event Registered",
        'tags': ['password-resets'],
        'text': 'Example text content',
        'to': [{'email': to_email,
                'name': user_name,
                'type': 'to'}],
    }
    result = mandrill_client.messages.send(message = message)
    print(result)
    status = result[0]["status"]
```

This is working fine. but I also want to send calendar. Is there a way to add calendar with mandrill or by any other method.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to send an .ics attachment?

Comment: @Carewen No not yet. will check it.